# Stopping the Jquery.map when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var parentEls = node.parents() 
    .map(function () {

        var curParentID = this.getAttribute("id"); 
        var curParentClass = this.getAttribute("class");

        if(curParentID) {
            return this.tagName + "#" + curParentID;
            /*stop the map function from proceeding*/
        } else {
            return this.tagName;
        }
    })
    .get().reverse().join(", ");
```

The above code helps to find search for unique id and once an ID is spotted , it creates the xpath. How can i stop the the map function once it has come to a point where the id is retrieved and the map function should stop? I tried return false and break but it does not work.

Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: Just use `.parentsUntil('[id]')` so you only have the tree up to the closest parent with an id attribute.

Comment: Could you give an example by answering? people can vote you suggestions if it is logical :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible using .map(), you may have to use .each() here

```
var temp = [];
node.parents().each(function () {
    var curParentID = this.getAttribute("id"); 
    var curParentClass = this.getAttribute("class"); 
    if(curParentID){
        temp.push(this.tagName + "#" + curParentID);
        return false;
    } else {
        temp.push(this.tagName);
    }
});
var parentEls = temp.reverse().join(", ");
```

Comment: But if i return false, it says :
i.e : HTML , BODY , false , false , false , false, A

Comment: @madi I forgot to change .map() to .each()

Comment: Ohhhh....hahaha now it makes sense...I was totally confused what was the difference.  hahaha....Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
   // parentsUntil() doesn't include the element specified by selector, 
   // so you need to add the closest ancestor with id attribute to the collection
   var parentEls = node.parentsUntil('[id]').add( node.closest('[id]') )
        .map(function () {
            return this.id ? '#' + this.id : this.tagName;
        })
        .get().join(", ");
```

Fiddle (updated): http://jsfiddle.net/SKqhc/5/

Comment: Yes this works awesome too. It does the same thing as above. Wonderful!